# MySQL - Simplify complex query for teacher/student subscribers

Tags: php, mysql, schema

For an online learning website, a teacher can create any courses they would like to teach. Each course has lessons. Students can then subscribe to these courses or any future courses the teacher adds if they choose to. Here are a three ways a student can subscribe to courses from a teacher:

1. Subscribe to **all courses** only (All current and future by teacher) **ex.** subscriber_id 12
2. Subscribe to **all courses** and then **unsubscribe individual courses** (Even if unsubscribed from all 
    current individual courses, they will still be subscribed to future ones) **ex.** subscriber_id 10 
3. Subscribe to **individual courses** only **ex.** subscriber_id 11

Here is what the subscribed_courses table looks like:

```
subscribed_courses (Table with all member chosen resort services)
teacher_id  subscriber_id  course_id    sub_type
    4            10            0          all
    4            10            1         unsub
    4            10            2         unsub
    4            11            4          sub
    4            12            0          all
```

When a teacher adds a new course, or a lesson, we need to scan the subscribed_courses table, and see which subscribed students should get an email. The problem is getting the below query to work to get the correct subscriber_ids to email. For this specific query example, let's use course_id 2, which just got a new lesson added, and we need to email all subscribers. There must be a better way to accomplish this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriber_id 
FROM subscribed_courses
WHERE teacher_id='4'
//AND #1 (sub_type='sub' AND course_id='2') //individually subscribed
      #2 ((sub_type='all' AND course_id='0') AND (sub_type='unsub' AND course_id<>'2')) //subscribed to all, ensure subscriber didn't unsub from this course [all subscribed 1 row + more row(s) for unsub]
      #3 (sub_type='all' AND course_id='0') //all subscribed [if this is one row only for subscriber]
```

Any idea how we can get the correct subscriber_ids in our situation or a better working solution?

Comment: What do you mean by the course_id=2 in the queries?

Comment: We were emailing course_id 2 subscribers. Just added that to the question, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** Try more succinct version

```
SELECT subscriber_id
  FROM subscribed_courses
 WHERE teacher_id = 4
   AND course_id IN(0, 2)
 GROUP BY teacher_id, subscriber_id
HAVING SUM(       
       CASE WHEN sub_type = 'all'   THEN 1  ELSE 0  END 
     + CASE WHEN sub_type = 'sub'   THEN 1  ELSE 0  END 
     + CASE WHEN sub_type = 'unsub' THEN -2 ELSE 0  END) > 0
```

Output:

```
| SUBSCRIBER_ID |
-----------------
|            12 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f23b9/18)** demo

Comment: You're right, it does look brutal and very complex. What does the ELSE -2 do? Also, I've never seen > 0 used before in a WHERE clause. So 2 things worry me, I don't fully understand the query (for upkeeping/changes), and I think if the table has 100s/1000s+ of subscribed courses, it will be really slow to run on every course/lesson added. What do you think? Is there a **more efficient** solution to this scenario (even if it includes a schema change)?

Comment: @Maverick Just updated the answer. MOre succinct version with no need to self-join. It should be efficient.

Comment: This looks much clearer. Can you explain the -2 part for an unsub and a little on how the logic works? This works great for this small test set, but would it work on a much bigger list? (I will test it multiple times with different variable settings for a while, just want your opinion on this)

Comment: @Maverick IMHO it will work just fine on your set of data, but to be sure you need to test it thoroughly. Now what it does it assigns a number to sub_type. To be subscribed you have to have a row with a value 'all' +1 and(or) a row 'sub' +1 (which can possibly make it 2). Now if you unsubscribed we assign -2. Then we calc a sum and see if it > 0 then it's a go. If <= then user either didn't subscribe or unsubscribed.

Comment: I love your simple logic. I'll accept your answer and test it thoroughly. If it acts different, I'll report back with a fiddle. Thanks for your quick solution & explanation!

Comment: @Maverick You're more than welcome :). **Note:** that in current state the query will work correctly only for one course_id (e.g. 2). As you can see it enforced via `WHERE ... course_id IN(0, 2)`. If you include more values e.g. `IN(0, 2, 3)` then the result will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you require. Thanks.

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscriber_id 
FROM subscribed_courses
WHERE teacher_id='4'
AND ((sub_type='sub' AND course_id='2')
union 
SELECT DISTINCT subscriber_id 
FROM subscribed_courses
WHERE teacher_id='4'
AND ((sub_type='all' AND course_id='0') AND (sub_type='unsub' AND course_id<>'2')) 
union
SELECT DISTINCT subscriber_id 
FROM subscribed_courses
WHERE teacher_id='4'
AND (sub_type='all' AND course_id='0'))
```

Comment: The problem is that this returns subscriber_ids 10 & 12. When only 12 should be returned since subscriber_id 10 individually unsubbed from course 2, and course 1, but is subbed to all others. The last query is overwriting the middle one in this solution.